# YouTube (Chrome) Extension that only displays videos from specific channel(s) on the landing page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api

I want to create a YouTube extension that only displays YouTube videos from selected channels on the landing page. I've looked everywhere, but I've only found how to hide certain videos or extensions where I don't know how they work, that filter by creator but also not on the landing page. Would that be possible, for example, by some extension of the URL or by changing the code via a Chrome extension? Best wishes!

Comment: can you add the extensions you found that filter by creator?

Comment: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/youfilter

Comment: my advice is that you need to search how to create a chrome extension, then, go step by step. For example: how you specify which channels are going to be used by the extension?, I'm affraid you need an specific scope in order to get more help.